# What does Chrome use as the key for decrypting my saved passwords?

Tags: password-management, google, chrome

When using Chrome, Chrome offers to remember my password on non-Google sites.

If my Google password is the key used to decrypt the other passwords that Chrome stores for me, wouldn't Chrome have to ask for my Google password every time it wants to auto fill one of my other passwords? Since it does not do this, it makes me think that my Google password is not the key, since Chrome supposedly does not store my actual Google password anywhere. So what is the key?

Or is my Google password stored somewhere 'securely' on my local device, and I just have to trust that Chrome only uses it when decrypting my passwords?

Note: this question assumes the OS is ChromeOS

Comment: I am actually interested in how Google stores these passwords when syncing them across devices (think passwords.google.com), but I will limit this question to just Chrome storing passwords locally.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this article](https://www.howtogeek.com/70146/how-secure-are-your-saved-chrome-browser-passwords/) it's your OS password instead of your Google pass.

Comment: The article doesn't discuss Chrome OS, only Windows. I will clarify question.